# Refresh JTable after adding records in an easier way than using a TableModel or fireRowValueChanged() methods

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, awt

I am doing a simple JTable program which doesn't have any serious code. Just the basic ones. Here is my code fragment

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class SampleClass implements ActionListener{
JFrame frame;
JTable table;
JButton button;

String columnName[] = {"Science"};
String rowName[][] = new String[10][1];

int i;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SampleClass obj = new SampleClass();
    obj.setRowValues();
    obj.build();
}
public void build() //Constructing GUI
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    table = new JTable(rowName, columnName);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    button = new JButton("New Value");

    frame.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
public void setRowValues() //Setting initial row values
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        rowName[i][0] = i + "           First";
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //Incrementing rowValues and repainting with no effect
    rowName[i][0] = "New Value";
    i++;
    table.repaint();
}
```

}

**Here my problem is when I click on button an extra value is added inside rowName[][] array. I want this to be reflected into the JTable table. I tried repaint() but it doesn't help. Please tell me the easiest way to update or refresh JTable**

I have seen other stackoverflow entries which uses AbstractTableModel and calling fireRowValueChanged() methods. Here I using just the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Refresh JTable after adding records in an easier way than using a TableModel or fireRowValueChanged() methods

The only proper way to do this is to update the TableModel. The TableModel will then invoke the proper fireXXX(...) method to notify the JTable of the change in data so the table can repaint itself. You never need to invoke repaint() manually.

To add a new row of data to the `DefaultTableModel` you can use the `addRow(...)` method.

Comment: Could you help me out here by updating my answer. I tried out DefaultTableModel but didn't work

Comment: @4k3R, `I tried out DefaultTableModel but didn't work` - where? I don't see the code you used so how can I make a suggestion. If you have never used the method before then you can always search the forum/web for examples.

Comment: Never mind.. I implemented DefaultTableModel ann used addRow(int arg) method to put a new row in the bottom (Although it was not what I was looking for).

Comment: @4k3R, you should be "accepting" the answer so people know the problem has been solved. `Although it was not what I was looking for` The addRow() method is the proper answer for your question. You need to understand how Swing components work. You should NEVER update the Array directly. In fact when you create the DefaultTableModel is copies the data from the Array to Vectors which are used by the DefaultTableModel to hold the data.